# How do I handle data being sent from a source that can only use basic GET/POST requests in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, post, cakephp-2.0

I'm wondering what the proper MVC mannor of handling the following senario is with CakePHP:

> I have a data source which is sending information to my website in the form of simple `GET`/`POST` requests.  To make the illustration simple, let's say it's data coming in about pizza deliveries.
>
> A `POST` from the source might contain a key/value combo of the driver's ID, the pizza's ID, and the current location of the pizza.  The website then needs to respond to this data with a simple status message - a good example would simply be `received/continue`.

Now, I want this data to require some sort of basic authentication... this can work in any mannor, as long as it verifies that the data is from a valid source.  I was thinking of just including POST data adding a userid and a passcode.

How do I incorporate this within CakePHP, so that it doesn't conflict in any way with other operations on the website, and also isn't overly exposed to security risks (mind that I doubt this will ever be a big enough website that someone will comb through it looking for holes).

Thank you!
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, so here's one off the top of my head:

- The request data ($_POST data) should be available either in `$this->request->data` in your controller, or in the `$_POST` itself (or perhaps both).
- To authenticate, you can use the good old [HTTP Auth](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). Perhaps not the brightest/safest solution, but probably good enough for your needs. Also, it is [already available](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-digest-and-basic-authentication-for-logging-in) in cake.
- You can respond to the post in several ways:

  - by disabling the response rendering and outputting response in the controller (`$this->autoRender = false; echo 'carry on old chap';`)
  - or (my preferred way) set the response layout to ajax and echo the output in your view.

Last but not least, there is no reason why any of this should affect the rest of your app, knock yourself out!

Comment: That's super good info, and gives me a great start.  The only one I'm caught up on is the HTTP Auth.  The client sending the information will not know how to handle an HTTP Auth request.  All it's really capable of is sending key/value pairs of GET/POST and receiving instructions in it's own script language.  Is there any way to put that to still put HTTP Auth to use, or should I just write up some sort of system of my own?

Comment: @xtraorange: Well, cake allows you to plug in your own authentication objects, so you can always invent something specific for your needs. If your client is "special", then you'll probably need to make a special auth object for it to handle it's requests. You can find more details in the book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects

Comment: Thanks, that takes care of it!  I appreciate the help.